# WP-API: how do I allow authenticated clients only?

Tags: oauth, wp-api

I set up an OAuth client for WP-API following the instructions for [WP-API/OAuth1 on github](https://github.com/WP-API/OAuth1/blob/master/docs/spec.md).

I was disappointed to realise afterwards that all of the site's content remains available over the API, including all sorts of not-really-public metadata like user registration dates. I don't want this.

How do I restrict the JSON API to allow OAuth clients only?

Answer (score 3):

This is how I did it, but I feel it could be better. For one thing, this results in HTTP 500... 403 would be preferable

```
add_filter( 'json_authentication_errors', function( $authenticated ) {
    if( !$authenticated ) {
        return new WP_Error('Access Denied');
    }
}, 99 );
```

(I understand this'll work for Basic Auth too)

Comment: Format `WP_Error` like this for appropriate response code `return new WP_Error( 'access_denied', __( 'Access denied', 'text_domain' ), array( 'status' => 403 ) );`

Comment: @Sisir, that doesn't make a difference to the eventual status code... could you be thinking of wp_die()?

Comment: Note that for WP-API v2 the hook is `rest_authentication_errors`

Answer (score 0):

Because I had to handle the error across a number of different areas of code in different classes, I made a global error in my auth handler:

```
function json_myauthname_auth_handler( $user = false) {
    global $wp_json_myauthname_auth_error; 
    $wp_json_myauthname_auth_error = null;
    ...
}
```

Then, if an error occurred anywhere I set the appropriate error code and message:

```
$wp_json_myauthname_auth_error = new WP_Error( 'json_login_failed', __( "We didn't recognize your email address or password. Please try again." ), array( 'status' => 401 ) );
```

Then all you need is a filter to handle the check for authentication errors

```
// Error handling 
function json_myauthname_auth_error( $error ) {
    // Passthrough other errors
    if ( ! empty( $error ) ) {
        return $error;
    }
}
add_filter( 'json_authentication_errors', 'json_myauthname_auth_error' );
```

If you don't need all of that you could just return the appropriate error:

```
return new WP_Error( 'json_login_failed', __( "We didn't recognize your email address or password. Please try again." ), array( 'status' => 401 ) );
```